# InputType in EditText inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-inputtype

In my `RecyclerView` some items have `EditText` (Inside `CardView`).It works fine without defining `InputType` in `EditText` but when I define `InputType` it causes the `RecyclerView` to scroll to position zero when `EditText` comes into focus(When touched on `EditText` to enter values).

This is a default `EditText` that works fine

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/box_blue_outline"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />
```

I have another `EditText` that accepts numbers only so I added `InputType`

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/box_blue_outline"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/number"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />
```

But clicking on this `EditText` to enter values, which has some position between the `RecyclerView` (say 7), it scrolls back to position 1.

Comment: If you have an `EditText` in 0 position it should scroll to 0 position when it gains focus. What is the problem exactly? Enlighten us with some code please.

Comment: add some code....so that we can see how you are rendering your data in recycler view

Comment: Adding all involved codes will not be easy but I'm adding all that can help understanding the issue

Answer (score 0):

Look like, different keyboard changes cause `RecyclerView` to update. It's very possible of the Window focus type. Try to change Keyboard behavior for appearing in `Activity/Fragment`  `onCreate`.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Please include all `View` layouts, where located `RecyclerView` and what layouts you are binding.